# Add class to parent div using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

This is should be fairly easy but for some reason I am struggling.

I have this following html structure

```
<div class="subcontent_detail>
  <h4>some text</h4>
  <div class="divider"></div>
  <div class="changevid"></div>
</div>
```

What I want is when changevid is clicked a class called 'active' should be added after subcontent

my code

```
$('.changevid').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$(this).parent().parent().addClass('active');
return false;
  });
```

Any help is highly welcomed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: ahhh again such a idiot I am..Thanks Paulie

Comment: And why `e.preventDefault();`, there is no default behaviour for DIV click and anyway, you are returning false

Comment: Too many calls to parent? If you are trying to apply the class to `.subcontent_detail` then you should only need one call to `parent()` since it is the immediate parent. You can also use `closest('.subcontent_detail')` as an alternative.

Comment: Actually I have few more lines of code which is not here.

Comment: I cannot believe you didn't try anything to resolve your issue before posting this question, if `.parent().parent()` was your issue, that's not serious...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You were calling `parent()` twice. This should work:

```
$('.changevid').click(function(e){
  $(this).parent().addClass('active');
});
```

Note you also don't need to `preventDefault()` or `return false` because the clicked element is not a link.

Comment: Thank you so much for the last bit of explanation.

Comment: Sorry have to wait 11 minutes

Comment: `return false;` could be to stop event propagation but not sure there is any reason OP would need it too