# What is the best way to add class to parent div jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parent

How do I add class to the parent div using jQuery, the following code works but is it good approach?

```
$("button > span:contains('Text')")
.parent()
.parent()
.parent()
.parent()
.parent()
.parent()
.addClass('test');
```

Comment: Yes, It is good.

Comment: isnt there any way to get top level div, if it has any specific class?

Comment: Use `closest("selector")`.

Comment: Does parent div has any class assigned to it?

Comment: Yes, I tried with closest but doesnt work. and parent div have specific class as well

Comment: if the particular parent has some class then plz use `.parents('.classname')`

Comment: Add the HTML code.

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26739798/add-class-to-parent-div-using-jquery

Answer (score 1):

You could use **[`.closest('parent_selector')`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)** instead if you want to get a top parent like :

```
$("button > span:contains('Text')").closest('top_parent_class_or_id').addClass('test');
```

```js
$("button > span:contains('Text')").closest('.top-parent').addClass('test');

console.log($('.top-parent').prop('class'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="top-parent">
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <button><span>Button Text</span></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `closest` to walk top parent div;

```
$("button > span:contains('Text')").closest('div')
```

Also you could use `parentsUntil()`

```
$("button > span:contains('Text')").parentsUntil('parentclassname_or_id')
```